# Is this a good example for documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-examples

There have been [significant contributions from multiple people](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/revisions/84?exampleId=16489) to [this "example"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/84/compile-and-run-your-first-java-program/16489/choosing-a-java-ide#t=201608301324032360181) in the Java tag.

But I think it is not a good example at all:

1. Picking an IDE is only tangentially related to the Java programming language.
2. You can pick it either by gut feeling or if you want to reach an objective decision the process becomes so complex it would be a complete topic not just one example.

My question is: Is there some kind of consensus, FAQ entry, or something that makes it obvious whether this is a good example or not? If there is no such consensus, let's try to establish one and make the result accessible in the FAQ.

Comment: Upcoming topics include: "Choosing a syntax coloring scheme" and "Deciding between tabs and spaces". Stay tuned!

Comment: vi vs emacs, anyone? Now *that* would be something hilarious.

Comment: it reads like an infomercial

Comment: @ppeterka emacs wins by a large margin with M-x butterfly

Comment: @CodyGray Example: tabs.  (post containing all tabs).  Example: spaces (post containing all spaces).  Example: mixed (post containing a program written in [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace-language))

Comment: @Yakk ...while the code still compiles as Java too... Bonus points if running it as whitespace and as Java result in the same output...

Comment: @ppeterka Does that qualify as Code Golf? Is that a  new category? May Code Juggling?

Comment: @JensSchauder I think it would qualify as "Don't try it at home" and should have an R Rating with warning signs all over the place emphasizing the mental health concerns of trying to get involved in it...